# How to view relationships in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Kepler. What do I click on to see parent/child relationships? I.e. account__r.contact.name

Comment: Are you trying to build queries or are you simply trying to determine parent-child relationships? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Good clarification. I am trying to build queries and need know how to connect the dots.

Comment: Assuming you have the Force.com IDE added, there is a file `salesforce.schema` in the project root that when double clicked opens a "Schema Explorer" that allows you to drill down into the various objects including the relationships.

Comment: Eclipse won't give you the `__r's`, you'll need to figure those out yourself when building queries. There are other tools which are much better suited to building queries for you. Unfortunate, my favorite (Salesforce's Ajax Tools) no longer works right now because of the Twitter AJax API it used having been retired (or something along those lines), but the next release of Symphonic Source's Cloudingo Studio will have the features you're looking for.